# Get slowest page results programmatically?

Tags: 2013, 2010, development, search, central-administration

We can get slowest page report through following path from central administration.

CA > Monitoring > View health reports

[image]

I want to gather this information by code. Please guide me if you have any reference code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get this information using APIs.

This is an admin page, that uses an internal class that eventually executes `dbo.proc_GetSlowestPages` from the `Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application` database.

You can try querying the database directly, but it is not a "good practice".

```
declare @webApp uniqueidentifier
select @webApp = WebApplicationId from dbo.RequestUsage where ServerUrl = 'http://myWebApplicationUrl'

declare @stime datetime
declare @etime datetime
set @stime = getDate() - 10
set @etime = getDate()

exec dbo.proc_GetSlowestPages 
@StartTime = @stime,
@EndTime = @etime,
@WebApplicationId = @WebApp,
@MachineName = null
```

Code snippet grabbed from [here](http://bbojilov.blogspot.se/2011/05/get-top-slowest-pages-in-sharepoint.html)